# Browser tries to reload same resource several times even when status is 200

Tags: java, spring, google-chrome

My application is trying to reload same resource several times but still resource is correctly loaded and status is 200. Application is trying to load *http://localhost:8080/scripts/app.js?_=1487686739222* and *http://localhost:8080/scripts/vendor.js?_=1487686739293* until browser doesn't stop with error. I tried disable cache but it still happens. When I try to load that resource manually resource is loaded correctly. I can't understand what is going wrong why should browser try to reload same resource several times. I'm using Spring and have this kind of configuration for loading ***index.html***

```
@Configuration
public class WebMvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    private String apiPath;

    private final ResourceProperties resourceProperties;

    @Autowired
    public WebMvcConfig(ResourceProperties resourceProperties) {
        this.resourceProperties = resourceProperties;
    }

    public WebMvcConfig(String apiPath, ResourceProperties resourceProperties) {
        this(resourceProperties);
        this.apiPath = apiPath;
    }

    private String getApiPath() {
        return apiPath;
    }

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry
            .addResourceHandler("/app/**", "/pages/**", "/components/**", "/sample", "/")
            .addResourceLocations(resourceProperties.getStaticLocations())
            .setCachePeriod(resourceProperties.getCachePeriod()).resourceChain(true)
            .addResolver(new SinglePageAppResourceResolver());
    }

    private class SinglePageAppResourceResolver extends PathResourceResolver {

        @Override
        protected Resource getResource(String resourcePath, Resource location) throws IOException {
            Resource resource = location.createRelative(resourcePath);
            if (resource.exists() && resource.isReadable()) {
                return resource;
            } else if (getApiPath() != null && ("/" + resourcePath).startsWith(getApiPath())) {
                return null;
            } else {
                resource = location.createRelative("index.html");
                return (resource.exists() && resource.isReadable()) ? resource : null;
            }
        }

    }

}
```

this is my security configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .csrf()
            .disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/api/public/**", "/app/**", "/pages/**", "/components/**", "/sample", "/apple-icon.png", "/favicon.ico", "/index.html", "/", "/scripts/**", "/styles/**")
            .permitAll()
            .anyRequest()
            .authenticated()
            .and()
            .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/pages/auth")
            .loginProcessingUrl("/api/public/auth")
            .permitAll()
            .and()
            .logout()
            .permitAll()
            .and()
            .exceptionHandling()
            .authenticationEntryPoint(new Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint());
    }

}
```

this is general data from request in chrome:

```
Request URL:http://localhost:8080/scripts/app.js?_=1487687587847
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200
```

Also here is console output:

```
Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.
Tried to load angular more than once.
```